# How to store PyQt5 QLineEdit responses into a dictionary at specific locations in dictionary

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have been using several line edits to get information from the user. I know I can create a signal using textchanged() and then connect it to a slot where I can extract the text that the user put in for that line edit.

But now suppose I want to store that information obtained from the specific line edits into a dictionary. For example, the user answers the `self.title = QLineEdit()`, this connects to a slot which populates the response in dictionary's "title" key. If the user answers the `self.product= QLineEdit()`, this connects to the same slot as before, but now populates the response in the dictionary's "Product" key. Similary, if any changes are made to those line edits later on, the dictionary should update with the new responses.

How can I do this? I want to avoid creating separate slots for every single QlineEdit as this can be tedious.

```
answers = {"title": "", "Date": "", "Product": "", "Serial Num": ""}
  def projectDetailsUI(self):
      layout = QGridLayout()
      self.title = QLineEdit()
      self.title.setFixedWidth(300)
      
      self.date = QLineEdit()
      self.date.setFixedWidth(120)
      
      self.product = QLineEdit()
      self.product.setFixedWidth(300)
      
      self.serialNum = QLineEdit()
      self.serialNum.setFixedWidth(300)
      
      font = QFont()
      title = QLabel("Project Details")
      title.setFont(font)
      layout.addWidget(title, 0,0)
      
      layout.addWidget(QLabel("Title"), 1,0)
      layout.addWidget(self.title, 1, 2)

      layout.addWidget(QLabel("Date (dd/mm/yy)"), 2, 0)
      layout.addWidget(self.date, 2, 2)

      layout.addWidget(QLabel("Name"), 3, 0)
      layout.addWidget(self.product, 3, 2)

      layout.addWidget(QLabel("Serial Number (if available)"), 4, 0)
      layout.addWidget(self.serialNum, 4, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're keeping pointers to each QLineEdit you can access their `text` property at anytime. The `textChanged` signal is emitted whenever the text is changed at all, a signal this frequent is not necessary. Instead connect each one's `editingFinished` signal to a single slot where all the keys are assigned values.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

answers = {"title": "", "Date": "", "Product": "", "Serial Num": ""}

class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.projectDetailsUI()
        
    def projectDetailsUI(self):
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.title = QLineEdit()
        self.title.setFixedWidth(300)

        self.date = QLineEdit()
        self.date.setFixedWidth(120)

        self.product = QLineEdit()
        self.product.setFixedWidth(300)

        self.serialNum = QLineEdit()
        self.serialNum.setFixedWidth(300)

        font = QFont()
        title = QLabel("Project Details")
        title.setFont(font)
        layout.addWidget(title, 0,0)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Title"), 1,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.title, 1, 2)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Date (dd/mm/yy)"), 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.date, 2, 2)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Name"), 3, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.product, 3, 2)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Serial Number (if available)"), 4, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.serialNum, 4, 2)

        self.title.editingFinished.connect(self.set_answers)
        self.date.editingFinished.connect(self.set_answers)
        self.product.editingFinished.connect(self.set_answers)
        self.serialNum.editingFinished.connect(self.set_answers)

    def set_answers(self):
        answers['title'] = self.title.text()
        answers['Date'] = self.date.text()
        answers['Product'] = self.product.text()
        answers['Serial Num'] = self.serialNum.text()
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Template()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```